# Fancybox error when opening it for the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancybox 1.3.4 on my site. I call the script on the change of the select control like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".xxx select").change(function () {
        var sExib = $(this).val();

        if (!isNaN(sExib))
            $.fancybox({
                'overlayShow': true,
                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                'href': '/url.aspx?yyy=' + sExib
            });
    });
});
```

In the first time it opens nicely. When I click a second time I got an error:
*Object doesn't support this property or method.*

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is there an Object associated with the error, or a line number?

Comment: using the developer tools debugging it shows that is stopping in the fancybox call

Answer (score 0):

It's probably trying to reinitialize the same object repeatedly. Try maybe attaching the fancybox to a jQuery selector?

Comment: How can I attach the fancybox to a select (combo box), to open when the seleciont changes?

Answer (score 0):

Researching the dropdown solution, I found out something that worked!
I just had to set the type of the fancybox to 'iframe'. It became like this:

```
            $.fancybox({
                'overlayShow': true,
                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                'type': 'iframe',
                'autoDimensions': true,
                'href': '/atlasdecobertura/Paginas/detalhesEmissora.aspx?exib=' + sExib
            });
```